# Order dates in MySQL with this format "01 August 2013"

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, date

how to order dates in ASC,

Dates are in the following format

```
01 January 2013

13 August 2013

27 June 2013
```

I've tried this query

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY TIMESTAMP(date) ASC
```

and this query

```
SELECT * FROM property_rent ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) ASC
```

Comment: What is your desired sort order?

Comment: from the oldest to the most recent. Can't seem to find the right date format to specify in str_to_date.

Comment: '%d %M %Y' should work (assuming all the rows have data in the same format)... however, why don't you just change the column type to DATE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [str_to_date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY str_to_date(date, 'your format here')
```

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY str_to_date(date, '%d %M %Y')
```

or similar.

Comment: seems to have the right answer.   check the sqlfiddle code [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62d60b/4)